# Getting Soap Fault on hitting a WebService using JMETER

Tags: web-services, testing, jmeter, soapui

I'm trying to contact a webservice via Jmeter (3.0), and I get the following error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="es-AR">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I haven't encountered any issues contacting the web service from SoapUI, so I'm wondering what could cause this problem.

**You can see the screen shots here:**

The HTTP Request within the tree, first part of the HTTP Request data, the HTTP Header Manager settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HxIK.jpg

[image]

Here are the results on SoapUI (works just fine):

[Results and log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDKpw.png)
[image]

Is it possible that the way that SoapUI sends the requests differs from the way Jmeter does and that's why it works?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: couldyou show your test plan ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this `action` bit to be a part of the `Content-Type` header like:

[image: Header Manager Settings]

I would also recommend adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) to your Test Plan

---

Out of interest, why don't you just record the request originated from SoapUI using [JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) like:

1. Configure JMeter for recording. The easiest way of doing this is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   - From JMeter main menu: `File - Templates - Recording - Create`
   - Workbench - HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder - Start

     [image: JMeter Proxy]
2. Configure SoapUI for recording

   - From SoapUI main menu: `Preferences - Proxy Settings`
   - Proxy Settting: manual, host: IP address or hostname of machine where JMeter is running, port: 8888

     [image: SoapUI proxy settings]
3. Execute request in SoapUI
4. Inspect the recorded request in JMeter under Workbench -> Recording Controller.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue, after editing the Content Type settings, I was able to send the request properly. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some trivial error in the value of http header `SOAPAction`.

Happened to notice(in the image you attached) that there are double quotes in its value.
Just remove the double quotes `"` from the `SOAPAction` value.

**UPDATE:**

It is noticed, while editing the question, that soapui has sent an additional http header `action` with a value (you masked the value).

So, please add `action` header in the jmeter request as well the right value in the `jmeter` plan.